# why we don't have to create separate xml file for menu (List View) using adapters , and if it is created automatically?

Tags: android-menu

```
package com.example.app1;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity
{
    String[] myarr = new String[12];    // defined above so it can be accessed by all methods
    {myarr[0] = "Starting Point";
    myarr[1] = "Starting Point1";
    myarr[2] = "Starting Point2";
    myarr[3] = "Starting Point3";
    myarr[4] = "Starting Point4";
    myarr[5] = "Starting Point5";
    myarr[6] = "Starting Point6";
    myarr[7] = "Starting Point7";
    myarr[8] = "Starting Point8";
    myarr[9] = "Starting Point9";
    myarr[10] = "Starting Point10";
    myarr[11] = "Starting Point11";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,myarr));
    }
```

i don't needed to create separate xml layout file for it rather menu displayed just fine on my android phone so why is it not required to create a separate xml and if it is created automatically then where i searched in layout folder but no i did'nt find it there toooo.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

> **android**.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1

the layout resource you are using comes from the android package (hence the android.* prefix). It means that the specific layout is part of Android, it can be found in any phone and it is one of the plenty resources that the platform provides for free. All resources provided by the platform can be found under the same package.

You can find strings that are translated to all languages inside android.R.string.* (i.e. android.R.string.ok,android.R.string.cancel), or colors to match the device you are running on (i.e. android.R.color.holo_blue_light, android.R.color.white).

You are free to use your own layout resource (that will actually appear in your project's res/layout folder) but most of the times, you need to use your own custom list adapter.

There are plenty of questions here on stackoverflow on how to create adapters and why they are needed.